# Will semaphore corrupt data transmission of peripherals like UART in a microcontroller?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, semaphore, freertos

Semaphore disables interrupts and so will this cause other operations like receiving data on SPI to get corrupt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling interrupts cannot corrupt the data on the hardware interface.

The problem is if the data is received by the hardware peripheral and then the it raises an interrupt to have the processor collect the data then this will be delayed.  If it is delayed for too long then potentially more data will have been received.  Depending on the peripheral, either the new data or the old data will have to be discarded.  Either way stream of data will be incomplete.

In most cases it is difficult to predict or test how long it is safe to disable interrupts for, so if possible it is best to avoid turning interrupts off.

If the peripheral includes a FIFO buffer, then the length of time that it is safe to disable interrupts for may be increased (although still difficult to predict).

Most modern microcontrollers have many ways to avoid disabling interrupts:

A better approach is to have the peripheral transfer the data to memory with DMA, so no interrupt is required at all.

Most modern processor cores provide ways to implement a semaphore do not even need to disable interrupts.

Comment: DMA doesn't rule out interrupt/polling of a flag, it just makes it far less frequent. Also DMA doesn't solve re-entrancy which is the purpose of semaphores, because you still have to protect reads of the DMA buffer from happening at memory locations where the hardware is currently writing.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way of implementing a semaphore. To disable all interrupts on the MCU is one way to do it, but it's a very poor amateur way of doing so. Because in more complex applications with multiple interrupts, this will make all real-time considerations and calculations a nightmare.

It creates subtle but severe bugs. Particularly when some quack has done so from deep inside some driver code. You import the driver into your project and suddenly previously working code breaks. In particular, be very careful about using various libs provided by silicon vendors - they are often of very poor quality.

There are better ways to do it, including:

- Ensuring atomic access of shared variables, which can only be done with inline assembler or C11 `_Atomic` if supported.
- Disabling one *specific* interrupt for a specific hardware peripheral, if it is possible to do do given the real-time considerations. Then this should be handled by the driver for that hardware peripheral in the form of setter/getter functions.
- Use a "poor man's semaphore" in the form of a plain flag variable, by relying on the interrupt mechanism of the MCU blocking all other interrupts while the ISR is executing. [Example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102).

Comment: This ignores the question.

Comment: @TomV I didn't see it that way. I read Lundin's answer as saying "Yes, it will corrupt other operations, if it has been implemented as Disable All Interrupts. But it should not be implemented that way." That looks to me like a direct answer to the question.

Comment: @DavidHoadley Lundin did not say "yes it will corrupt other operations" if he did that would be an incorrect answer but still an answer.  He just said "you should not do that".  This is completely correct but does not in any way answer whether it will corrupt the transfer.  The answer to which is "maybe or maybe not depending on how long you disable them for"

Comment: @TomV The question is "will this cause other _operations_ like receiving data on SPI to get corrupt" and it will absolutely do that, in case the SPI reception relies on RX flags getting cleared by an ISR in a timely manner.

Comment: So every microcontroller project from the beginning of time to the mid-90s has corrupt data? of course not!

Comment: @TomV None but you have been talking about corrupt data. Though in the case of SPI, lets say running at 100kHz, no buffers and using an ISR for rx decoding (fairly common scenario), then this ISR will get triggered once every 10us. If you disable all interrupts, you then need to ensure that the code running during disabling as well as the interrupt latency of the given core doesn't exceed 10us. Otherwise the flag register won't get cleared. This could in turn either leading to an overrun or that the next incoming byte gets discarded.